# Laravel validator response nested arrays

Tags: php, json, validation, laravel, vue.js

Is it possible to expand validator responses from nested arrays. Typically Laravel responds with the "dot notation" for example:

```
    [
        'organisation.name'          => 'required|max:60|min:3',
        'organisation.avatar'        => '',
        'organisation.phone'         => 'required|max:25|min:5',
        'organisation.paid_staff'    => 'required|numeric'
    ]
```

An error with `organisation.name` wold return:

```
{
  "message": "422 Unprocessable Entity",
  "errors": {
    "organisation.name": [
      "The organisation name has already been taken."
    ]
  },
  "statusCode": 422
};
```

Where i would like to have the dot notation expanded as such:

```
{
  "message": "422 Unprocessable Entity",
  "errors": {
    "organisation": {
        "name": [
            "The organisation name has already been taken."
        ]
    }
  },
  "statusCode": 422
};
```

Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: I would also like to know if this is possible and how, great question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We achieved this outcome by extending the `App\Exceptions\Handler` class method `invalidJson()` as follows:

```
/**
 * Convert a validation exception into a JSON response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
protected function invalidJson($request, ValidationException $exception)
{
    $jsonResponse = parent::invalidJson($request, $exception);

    $original = (array) $jsonResponse->getData();

    $jsonResponse->setData(array_merge($original, [
        'statusCode'    => $exception->status,
        'errors'        => Arrays::expandDotNotationKeys((array) $original['errors']),
    ]));

    return $jsonResponse;
}
```

We have a Utility class called `Arrays` with a method `expandDotNotationKeys()` that looks like this:

```
/**
 * Expands arrays with keys that have dot notation
 *
 * @param Array $array
 *
 * @return Array
 */
public static function expandDotNotationKeys(Array $array)
{
    $result = [];

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
      array_set($result, $key, $value);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Done! no need to change native language files.

Comment: sorry but, i dont follow, what i have to do with this code?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this myself yet, but looking at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-error-messages) give a hint -

> In many cases, you may wish to specify your attribute specific custom
>   messages in a language file instead of passing them directly to the
>   Validator. To do so, add your messages to custom array in the
>   resources/lang/xx/validation.php language file.

**Your Language File**

```
'custom' => [
    'organisations' => [
        'name' => [
             'required' => 'The organisation name has already been taken!',
        ],
    ],
],
```